# Can I have two delimiters for getParameter method from ServletRequest?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url, servlets, request

I have a class something like,

```
 public class Sample {
      @Autowired
      private HttpServletRequest request;

      //This method which reads the param value from URL.
      protected Sample sampleMethod() {
           String param = request.getParameter("param");
      }
  }
```

The URL is generated from a page which actually has something like this:

```
https://www.example.com/page?a=b&param=sample?b=c
```

So when my page reads it, the value of param becomes **sample?b=c**.
Instead of that will I be able to make the getParameter method to read only till **sample**,making it to use "?" also as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you have an amp(&) after sample in your request as shown below:

```
https://www.example.com/page?a=b&param=sample&b=c
```

`?` in a query string is used as a starter which should be used exactly once and at the beginning of the query string.

Just in case you have `?` as a part of data you can always use get the query string by using `getQueryString()`

```
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
```

Based on any delimiter you can always split up this string.